# Generating a VCARD with php QRcodes

Tags: php, qr-code, vcf-vcard

i try to generate VCARDS with http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ with the following code

```
<?php
include('myclasses/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
QRcode::png("BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:Mustermann;Max FN:Max Mustermann ORG:Firma",
"myclasses/phpqrcode/test2.png", "L", 4, 4);
echo '<img src="myclasses/phpqrcode/test2.png" />'; 
php?>
```

Has anyone an idea whats wrong ? the scanner gets an empty vcard !

thanx

Comment: That's not how you close a php file, use `?>` instead of `php?>` at the end.

Comment: What does your scanner say if you try this: QRcode::png("BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nN:Mustermann;Max\r\nFN:Max Mustermann\r\nORG:Firma", "myclasses/phpqrcode/test2.png", "L", 4, 4);

Answer (score 3):

A standard vCard looks like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Example_vCard_files

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Gump;Forrest
TEL;WORK;VOICE:(111) 555-1212
END:VCARD
```

Notice that there is a new line after every field.

Your card says

```
BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:Mustermann;Max FN:Max Mustermann ORG:Firma
```

There are no newlines so the vCard scanner is getting confused.

You need to explicitly put in newlines to make it work.  For example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nN:Mustermann;Max\nFN:Max Mustermann\nORG:Firma
```

That should make your card work.